# Age swapping between humans

Tags: mahabharata, human, boon

Yayati got a boon from Sukra that he can swap his old age with anyone

> "Vaisampayana continued, 'Yayati, the son of Nahusha, thus cursed by
>   the angry Usanas, was then divested of his youth and immediately
>   overcome by decrepitude. And Yayati said, 'O son of Bhrigu, I have not
>   yet been satiated with youth or with Devayani. Therefore, O Brahmana,
>   be graceful unto me so that decrepitude might not touch me.' **Sukra
>   then answered, 'I never speak an untruth. Even now, O king, art thou
>   attacked by decrepitude. But if thou likest, thou art competent to
>   transfer this thy decrepitude to another.**' Yayati said, 'O Brahmana,
>   let it be commanded by thee that that son of mine who giveth me his
>   youth shall enjoy my kingdom, and shall achieve both virtue and fame.'
>   Sukra replied, 'O son of Nahusha, thinking of me thou mayst transfer
>   this thy decrepitude to whomsoever thou likest. That son who shall
>   give thee his youth shall become thy successor to the throne. He shall
>   also have long life, wide fame, and numerous progeny!'"
>
> [[SECTION LXXXIII, Sambhava Parva, Adi parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01084.htm)

Yayati uses the boon and transfers his old age to his son Puru and becomes young by recieving his sons age

> "Yayati at last turned to his youngest child, Puru, and addressing him
>   said, 'Thou art, O Puru, my youngest son! But thou shall be the first
>   of all! Decrepitude, wrinkles, and whiteness of hair have come over me
>   in consequence of the curse of Kavya called also Usanas. I have not
>   yet however, been satiated with my youth. O Puru, take thou this my
>   weakness and decrepitude! With thy youth I shall enjoy for some years
>   the pleasures of life. And when a thousand years have passed away, I
>   shall give back to thee thy youth and take back my own decrepitude.'
>
> "Vaisampayana said, 'Thus addressed by the king, Puru answered with
>   humility, 'I shall do, O monarch, as thou bidest me. I shall take, O
>   king, thy weakness and decrepitude. Take thou my youth and enjoy as
>   thou listest the pleasures of life. Covered with thy decrepitude and
>   becoming old, I shall, as thou commandest, continue to live, giving
>   thee my youth.' Yayati then said, 'O Puru, I have been gratified with
>   thee. And being gratified, I tell thee that the people in thy kingdom
>   shall have all their desires fulfilled.'
>
> **"And having said this, the great ascetic Yayati, then thinking of
>   Kavya, transferred his decrepitude unto the body of the high-souled
>   Puru.'"**
>
> [[SECTION LXXXIV, Sambhava Parva, Adi parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01085.htm)

---

Are there any other historical stories in Hindu scriptures that involves the concept of age swapping between humans?

Comment: I think saying "historical stories from scripture" would be more suitable that "true stories..."

Comment: What do you mean by true? That's opinion based. Better change it to some other word.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=story+meaning&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 ... Story can be imaginary also. SO I kept that word...

Comment: As far as I know no stories within Hinduism have ever shown to be true.

Comment: In that sense, nothing can be proved true. Religion is based on faith and belief. No one's verified if those stories mentioned in any book say Purana or Itihasa as true. How will you verify if they're true? Belief right?  Questions should not reflect single person's perspective. It reflects site also.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma True w.r.t Hinduism and not w.r.t science.

Comment: What to believe as true or not differs from person to person. Not every Hindu believes everything to be true. There are differences in this also. I am asking about verification. How will you verify or understand the story is true?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I mean true according to Mahabharata. True according to scriptures. If I show any statement that says t all statements in the text is true? Verification is for proof and is for science only.

Comment: If you mean "true according to scriptures", you already added "stories from *scriptures*". Adding true implies verification in some way.  Answers on our site also needs verification. "Verification is for proof and is for science only" . No, many things need verification. But in this question it seems you are just looking stories from scriptures believing to be true.  Our site doesn't state any story in scriptures to be false. So better to remove true as it's redundant.You already mentioned from scriptures. But not everything in scriptures is true. Some are exaggerations.

Comment: "But not everything in scriptures is true" this sounds like you are in conflict with yourself. "How will you verify if they're true?" The burden of proof is on the on the one who poses it to be true. "No one's verified if those stories mentioned in any book say Purana or Itihasa as true." Exactly, so rejecting these stories as nonfiction seems to be the wise course of action.

Comment: “Transfer thy decrepitude”  After Yayati came back did his son get his youth back ? Did Puru never live a normal life with youth/health at all ?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is  about age swapping or exchanging some of the  age of one person  to another in order to give him some years of life or to revive him from death .

Yes there is yet another intresting story of  [**Saint  Ruru**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Ruru) and his bride Pramadvara  in [**Mahabharata**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01010.htm)- Adi Parva- Pauloma Parva- Chapter 8-9. Saint Ruru swiped half of his life for his bride Pramadvara , when she was bitten by snake and became dead.

---

**Brief of the story** - Once Menaka ,the celestial dancing-girl gave birth to a child from the  King of the Gandharvas  Viswavasu near the hermitage of Rishi Sthulakesha. Menaka abandoned this  new born child  on the shore of  the river flowing nearby. Rishi Sthulakesha seeing the  child ,filling with compassion took it to the hermitage and raised her. As she was more  in beautifulness among the beautiful ladies of the world the Rishi named her "Pramadvara"

One day a saint called "Ruru" saw "Pramadvara" in the hermitage, he asked the hand of Pramadvara in marriage through his friends and father. Rishi Sthulakesha accepted and agreed to gave Pramadvara to Ruru in marriage. And fixed their marriage some time later on one auspacious day.

One day Pramadvara went into the woods with her lady companions for recreational purpose. In the woods at one place on the way  a snake was laying in coil. But Pramadvara didn't saw the snake and did kept her foot on him while walking. Then snake did bitten her with his venomous teeth and she became dead by his venom.

Saint Ruru knowing his Bride   dead  became overwhelmed with  grief and  intense sorrow  about  loss of his bride. He went into woods and started weeping loudly. Then a a messenger from heaven came there and told Ruru that she was a gandharva child and her days were over , so she died. Ruru asked a way with which she could be alive again to that messenger and that messenger told Ruru that ,she will be alive again if he is willing to spare half of his life and gave it to her. Ruru agreed and the Pramadvara was revived again by the god Dharma.

---

P. 51

> देवदूत उवाच
>
> आयुषोSर्ध प्रयच्छ त्वं कन्यायै भृगुनन्दन |
>  एवमुत्थास्यति रुरो तव
>   भार्या प्रमद्वरा ||11||
>
> "And Ruru replied, O messenger of heaven! What is that which the gods
>   have ordained. Tell me in full so that (on hearing) I may comply with
>   it. It behoveth thee to deliver me from grief!' **And the celestial
>   messenger said unto Ruru, 'Resign half of thy own life to thy bride,**
>   and then, O Ruru of the race of Bhrigu, thy Pramadvara shall rise from
>   the ground
>
> ---
>
> रुरु उवाच 
> आयुषोSर्ध प्रयच्छामि कन्यायै खेचरोत्तम |
>  शृङ्गाररूपाभरणा
>   समुत्तिष्ठतु मे प्रिया : ||12 ||
>
> O best of celestial messengers, **I most willingly offer a moiety of my
>   own life in favour of my bride.** Then let my beloved one rise up once
>   more in her dress and lovable form.'
>
> ---
>
> "Sauti said, 'Then the king of Gandharvas (the father of Pramadvara)
>   and the celestial messenger, both of excellent qualities, went to the
>   god Dharma (the Judge of the dead) and addressed him, saying, 'If it
>   be thy will, O Dharmaraja, let the amiable Pramadvara, the betrothed
>   wife of Ruru, now lying dead, rise up with a moiety of Ruru's life.'
>   **And Dharmaraja answered, 'O messenger of the gods, if it be thy wish,
>   let Pramadvara, the betrothed wife of Ruru, rise up endued with a
>   moiety of Ruru's life.'**
>
> "Sauti continued, 'And when Dharmaraja had said so, that maiden of
>   superior complexion, Pramadvara, endued with a moiety of Ruru's life,
>   rose as from her slumber. This bestowal by Ruru of a moiety of his own
>   span of life to resuscitate his bride afterwards led, as it would be
>   seen, to a curtailment of Ruru's life.

So in this way saint Ruru gave  half of his life to his bride Pramadvara when she was dead and swiped his life.